# do power amps need regulated power supply

Tags: voltage-regulator, amplifier, zener

Does a power amplifier needs a voltage regulator since it needs to draw current around 2 A depending on the wattage and speaker impedance. If we try to use a zener regulator, notice that a zener diode's maximum current is only at 200 mA which is way lower than the 2 Ampere current requirement to drive a speaker. Or will a plain unregulated dc supply will work (no more zener but we risk getting variable supply voltage)?

Comment: Olin's answer is great, but two more comments: 1) A zener regulator is almost never the right answer for anything over a few mA.  Linear regulators almost always preferred, and they're pretty inexpensive.  2) A "regulated" power supply doesn't necessarily mean you're using a linear regulator.  A high quality DC-DC (switching) converter will always have better efficiency, and the additional noise is generally acceptable (although it is something you need to double check).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A power amplifier does not *need* a regulated supply depending on how it is specified.  Some may need a regulated supply to meet their stated power line noise output limits.  Others may need a regulated supply to deliver their maximum rated power without overheating.

It is certainly possible to design a audio power amplifier to a useful set of specifications while allowing its DC power voltage to fluctuate over some limits.  Allowing the power supply to ripple introduces two design challenges, to not let the ripple get into the output signal, and to make the amp work as specified over the full range of minimum to maximum power voltage.

Keeping the power supply noise out of the output signal is quantified as power supply rejection, usually expressed in dB.  Negative feedback is one important way to increase power supply rejection.  Take a look at the feedback equation and see how it inherently does this.  However, you don't want global feedback too high because you otherwise get into other problems, like transcient intermodulation (TIM) distortion.  The circuit topology is also important.  As a simplistic example, consider a emitter follower.  Changes in the collector voltage are greatly attenuated onto the emitter voltage output.

Making the amp work over a range of DC input voltage is mostly about being careful about dissipation.  Assuming the amp can only drive the output within its power supply range minus a little headroom, the lowest power voltage therefore dictates the maximum output power.  However, the most dissipation will occur at the highest power voltage.  You need to make sure the amp can handle the rated output power at the highest power voltage without overheating.  A class D amp deals with this issue nicely in that it is essentially a switching power supply that runs at audio rates.

Comment: tnx @olin, i just observe that power amplifier circuits rarely need regulated supplies.

Comment: +1, and I would +2 if I could... Really nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about a system level solution, using a buck would definitely help you reduce the input current seen by the system. The idea stems from the efficiency curve of a typical Class-D amp. With higher efficiencies at lower bias voltages and vice versa, bucking the bias voltage would considerably improve the performance without affecting the sound quality. This is because, for the most part of a typical amp use, the power output meanders around the 0.5 W/Ch (ie. we do not need a very large headroom). If you are thinking of using a regulator for only one amp though, the losses in the buck would certainly be larger than the power you would save by giving the amp a lower bias.